# prevent PowerShell autocomplete from adding dot prefix

Tags: powershell, autocomplete

I understand why PowerShell requires that I prefix a command `foo.exe` with `.\foo.exe` when I run it. So if I am typing a command `fo` and hit `Tab`, autocomplete changes what I typed to `.\foo.exe`. I can live with that.

The problem is when `foo.exe` takes command-line arguments, and one of them is the `bar.dat` file. If I'm typing `.\foo.exe ba` and hit `Tab`, I want to get `.\foo.exe bar.dat`. I do *not* want to get `.\foo.exe .\bar.dat`. Not only is this annoying as heck (not to mention ugly), it actually breaks some of my commands, which don't allow any directory (even the current directory) to be specified in the argument.

How do I turn off this PowerShell quirk of adding a `.\` to every single autocomplete for something in the current directory? As far as I'm concerned, I'd like it to be turned off everywhere—I can remember to type `.\foo.exe` instead of `foo.exe` for the initial command.

If there is no way to turn this off, I'm throwing PowerShell away and moving back to `cmd`.

I have opened [PowerShell Issue #18180](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/18180).

Comment: Can't seem to find a way to change this behavior.

Comment: Ditto to what 'LPChip' stated, but when using the CLI this way, you have to fully qualify calls to external commands. It's just a habit one needs to get into.  MS has this documented here: [PowerShell- Running Executables - TechNet Articles - United States (English) - TechNet Wiki]
(https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.asp)  --- see example 5. Note in the samples, you don't have to leave PS to use cmd directly as well. Lastly to avoid this. don't use tab in the CLI for external calls. Use the spacebar. Well, I do, just becasue.

Comment: "… you have to fully qualify calls to external commands." This question is not about whether I have to fully qualify calls to external commands. This question is about PowerShell blindly adding a dot prefix to every autocomplete I do, even if it's not a command (i.e. even if it's not at the first of the string). Note that PowerShell could still _require_ dot prefixes to commands without adding the dots with autocomplete. But I'll accept auto-complete adding dots for the command. I don't want auto-complete to add dots to other strings, e.g. command-line options.

Comment: There's an irony that someone just now tried to edit my post, saying, "Removed extraneous "." and "\" at the start of the command to avoid a distraction."  That's exactly the point! PowerShell forces the dot prefix for `.\foo.exe`; that I understand to an extent. But then its autocomplete forces the same prefix for `.\bar.dat` as well!

Comment: There's no irony: your post had `.foo.exe` (sic) - something that wouldn't have worked. Glad you corrected your own typo.

Comment: Yep, mklement0, the `.foo.exe` was a typo and should have been `.\foo.exe`; noticing that was good, thanks. It should have been corrected. But to say it should be removed because it is distracting in some way proves my point.  But I'm curious how you managed to put ".\" in backticks without Stack Overflow's parser thinking the backslash should be removed, apparently because it thinks it is an escape character? If I write ".\" using backticks instead of quotes it winds up like `.\` you see here.

Answer (score 1):

**As of PowerShell 7.3.1, PowerShell *invariably* auto-completes the names of files and subdirectories *in the current directory* with a preceding `.\`** (`./` on Unix-like platforms)

- For *programs* (executables) - i.e. the *first* token in a statement - this is a *must*, because PowerShell by design requires you to signal the intent to execute a program located in the *current* directory explicitly.
- For program *arguments* - subsequent tokens - this is generally *not* needed - but *usually* does no harm.

If you'd like to see PowerShell omit the `.\` / `./` prefix in the latter case, I encourage you to open an issue in the [PowerShell repo](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues). [*Update*: You've since opened [GitHub issue #18180](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/18180)]

---

**Workarounds**:

- **For *all* commands and their arguments**, whether they're PowerShell-native or external programs:

  - **Redefine the built-in `TabExpansion2` function**<sup>[1]</sup> in order to remove the `.\` prefix from completion results after the fact: see the code in [this comment](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/18180#issuecomment-1261140386) on the GitHub issue you've created, courtesy of [@MartinGC94](https://github.com/MartinGC94)
  - Here's an adaption that also handles `./` accordingly, so as to also support Unix-like platforms; place it in your [`$PROFILE`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles) file to make it available by default in all future sessions.

```sh
# Adapted from: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/18180#issuecomment-1261140386
# Credit belongs to MartinGC94 (https://github.com/MartinGC94)
function TabExpansion2 {
  <# Options include:
        RelativeFilePaths - [bool]
            Always resolve file paths using Resolve-Path -Relative.
            The default is to use some heuristics to guess if relative or absolute is better.

      To customize your own custom options, pass a hashtable to CompleteInput, e.g.
            return [System.Management.Automation.CommandCompletion]::CompleteInput($inputScript, $cursorColumn,
                @{ RelativeFilePaths=$false }
    #>

  [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'ScriptInputSet')]
  [OutputType([System.Management.Automation.CommandCompletion])]
  Param
  (
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'ScriptInputSet', Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
    [string] $inputScript,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'ScriptInputSet', Position = 1)]
    [int] $cursorColumn = $inputScript.Length,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'AstInputSet', Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
    [System.Management.Automation.Language.Ast] $ast,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'AstInputSet', Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]
    [System.Management.Automation.Language.Token[]] $tokens,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'AstInputSet', Mandatory = $true, Position = 2)]
    [System.Management.Automation.Language.IScriptPosition] $positionOfCursor,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'ScriptInputSet', Position = 2)]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'AstInputSet', Position = 3)]
    [Hashtable] $options = $null
  )

  Set-StrictMode -Version 1

  # The original TabExpansion2 code.
  $completionOutput =
    if ($psCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'ScriptInputSet') {
      [System.Management.Automation.CommandCompletion]::CompleteInput(
        <#inputScript#>  $inputScript,
        <#cursorColumn#> $cursorColumn,
        <#options#>      $options)
    }
    else {
      [System.Management.Automation.CommandCompletion]::CompleteInput(
        <#ast#>              $ast,
        <#tokens#>           $tokens,
        <#positionOfCursor#> $positionOfCursor,
        <#options#>          $options)
    }

  # Custom post-processing that removes a .\ or ./ prefix, if present.
  $completionOutput.CompletionMatches = @(
    foreach ($item in $CompletionOutput.CompletionMatches) {
      $isFileOrDirArg =
        if ($item.ResultType -in [System.Management.Automation.CompletionResultType]::ProviderContainer, [System.Management.Automation.CompletionResultType]::ProviderItem) {
          # A file / directory (provider item / container) path, 
          # though we must rule out that it acts *as a command*,
          # given that the "./" \ "\." prefix is *required* when invoking files located in the current dir.

          # Tokenize the part of the input command line up to the cursor position.
          $pstokens = [System.Management.Automation.PSParser]::Tokenize($inputScript.Substring(0, $cursorColumn), [ref] $null)

          # Determine if the last token is an argument.
          switch ($pstokens[-1].Type) {
            'CommandArgument' {
              # An unquoted argument.
              $true; break 
            } 
            { $_ -in 'String', 'Number' } { 
              # Either:
              #  * A quoted string, which may be an argument or command;
              #    Note that in the end it is only treated as a command if preceded by '.' or '&'
              #  * A number which matches a filename that starts with a number, e.g. "7z.cmd"
              switch ($pstokens[-2].Type) {
                $null { $false; break } # Token at hand is first token? -> command.
                'Operator' { $pstokens[-2].Content -notin '.', '&', '|', '&&', '||'; break } # If preceded by a call operator or an operator that starts a new command -> command
                'GroupStart' { $false; break } # Preceded by "{", "(", "$(", or "@(" -> command.
                'StatementSeparator' { $false; break } # Preceded by ";", i.e. the end of the previous statement -> command
                Default { $true } # Everything else: assume an argument.
              }
            }
          }
        }
      if ($isFileOrDirArg) {
        # A file / directory (provider item / container) path acting as an *argument*
        [System.Management.Automation.CompletionResult]::new(($item.CompletionText -replace '^([''"]?)\.[/\\]', '$1'), $item.ListItemText, $item.ResultType, $item.ToolTip)
      } 
      else {
        # Otherwise, pass through.
        $item
      }
    }
  )
  return $completionOutput
}
```

- **For the *arguments* of *specific* external programs**:

  - You can use [`Register-ArgumentCompleter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/register-argumentcompleter) to implement *custom* tab-completion for a given command (which may be an external executable, indicated with `-Native`).
  - However, only *explicitly enumerated* commands can have custom completers installed, so you'd have to *list them individually* in the `-CommandName` argument below.
  - The following command implements file-name-only completion for `foo.exe` - if you place it in your [`$PROFILE`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles) file, it will be available in future sessions too:

    ```sh
     # Note: If foo.exe is located in the *current* directory, replace
     #       'foo' with '.\foo'
     Register-ArgumentCompleter -Native -CommandName foo -ScriptBlock {
       param($wordToComplete)
       Get-ChildItem -Name -File $wordToComplete*
     }
    ```

    - Note: This is a simplistic implementation that assumes that what you type is a file *name* only; if you type a *relative path*, it will also tab-complete to the name only, so the path component is lost. More work is needed to handle this case.

---

<sup>[1] PowerShell uses this built-in function to get tab-completion results. Overriding it allows you to customize the behavior. The custom function shown incorporates the code of the built-in function (whose body you can examine with `$function:TabExpansion2`) and performs post-processing on the default results to remove the `.\` / `./` prefix. [Source-code link](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/fd67038ed88a844c51bcadbd720e6c2335fa4900/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/InitialSessionState.cs#L3988) to the function definition, current as of this writing.</sup>

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141595/discussion-on-answer-by-mklement0-prevent-powershell-autocomplete-from-adding-do).